# PHP DomDocument to replace pattern

Tags: php, search, replace, pattern-matching, domdocument

I need to find and replace http links to hyperlinks. These http links are inside span tags.

$text has html page. One of the span tags has something like

```
<span class="styleonetwo" >http://www.cnn.com/live-event</span>
```

Here is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $anchor) {
    $link = $anchor->nodeValue;
    if(substr($link, 0, 4) == "http")
    {
        $link = "<a href=\"$link\">$link</a>";
    }
    if(substr($link, 0, 3) == "www")
    {
        $link = "<a href=\"http://$link\">$link</a>";
    }    
    $anchor->nodeValue = $link;
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

It works ok. However...I want this to work even if the data inside span is something like:

```
<span class="styleonetwo" > sometexthere http://www.cnn.com/live-event somemoretexthere</span>
```

Obviously above code wont work for this situation. Is there a way we can search and replace a pattern using DOMDocument without using preg_replace?

**Update:** To answer phil's question regarding preg_replace:

I used regexpal.com to test the following pattern matching:

```
\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|(www|ftp)\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

It works great in the regextester provided in regexpal. When I use the same pattern in PHP code, I got tons of weird errors. I got unknown modifier error even for escape character! Following is my code for preg_replace

```
$httpRegex = '/\b(\?:(\?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|(www|ftp)\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%\?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]/';
$cleanText = preg_replace($httpRegex, "<a href='$0'>$0</a>", $text);
```

I was so frustrated with "unknown modifiers" and pursued DOMDocument to solve my problem.

Comment: What's the problem with `preg_replace()`?

Comment: Your regex is not escaped. You have to escape the escape character and the delimiter!

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions well suit this problem - so better use `preg_replace`.

Now you just have several unescaped [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in your pattern, so escape them or choose another character as the delimiter - for instance, `^`. Thus, the correct pattern would be:

```
$httpRegex = '^\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|(www|ftp)\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%\?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]^i';
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita! It helps. When I do preg_replace($httpRegex, "<a href='$0'>$0</a>", $text); it gives me a link without "http". I could replace the code with preg_replace($httpRegex, "http://$0", $text); But, it would give me `code`http://http://`code` if the link in the text is `code`http://something`code`. I could have links like `code`<span>wwww.link.com</span>`code` or `code`<span>http://www.link.com</span>`code`. Should I need to write two regex to solve this? Thanks again.

Comment: I would use a `preg_replace_callback` function - here's an example: http://pastebin.com/GfPjtbku